# Is converting from PNG to WebP format still effective to prevent facial recognition?

Tags: image, facial-recognition

[Fawkes](https://sandlab.cs.uchicago.edu/fawkes/) was used to cloak the PNG images and the images were then converted from PNG to WebP format using Google's official `cwebp.exe`. Is the cloaking still effective to prevent facial recognition on the converted images?

The usage for the cloaking software is to make pictures of humans unidentifiable to malicious bots (preventing/making facial recognition harder).

I use the `-q 80` setting

Comment: The link you provided says that particular versions are not effective against Azure. The most recent version is. What are you asking, then?

Comment: I am using the newest version. The question has been rewritten

Comment: Right, I get that. The author says that it is effective. What are you asking for?

Comment: Whether the cloaking doesn't become not effective due to the changing of the pixels due to compression

Comment: @Munchkin its kind of a moot point tbh.  Any image you upload on the internet is there FOREVER ... any "cloaked" photos you uploaded previously using older Fawkes algorithm are now susceptible, and while the new versions claim to still work ... they wont in the semi near future.  Its a constant game of cat and mouse, cept your loose conditions are based on them not being able to build a profile on you ... from pictures that are already available too them.  Only winning move is to not play ... dont upload photoes of yourself online.